# Mount&Blade Warband Steam Version Problem

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

So I bought Mount and Blade Warband a month ago on steam and for some reason I'm not getting any achievements and everytime I turn on the game one small window is popping up with a CD key and asking me to activate it. Anyone know or have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The usual first response about problems with Steam games is to Verily Game Integrity (Right-click on game in library/Properties/Local Files/Verify Integrity...)
 or uninstall/reinstall. I believe the window you're referring to is a rather regular annoyance on Steam and I don't think is the cause of the problem. Do give a screenshot or copy the text of that particular windows, though.

Comment: Did you activate the cheats? When the game starts you get a config window, you can click allow cheats there, when you do achievements are disabled